# VCard not detecting in my mobile app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, qr-code, barcode-scanner

Hi I dont know in which category i should put this question, but since I am implementing VCard in ASP.NET MVC, I am putting this question in this category.

Basically I am working on VCard code generator project. I am using query string for this.
Problem is  when I scan code in my mobile app, it is not detecting VCard. This is my code :

```
  QrString += "var compiled_card_data = \"BEGIN:VCARD\" + \";\" +";
            QrString += "\"VERSION:3.0\" + \";\" +";
            QrString += "\"N:\" + lastname + \";\" + firstname + \";\" +";
             QrString += "\"FN:\" + firstname + \";\" +";  
            QrString += "\"URL:\" + url + \";\" + ";
            QrString += "\"EMAIL:\" + email + \";\" +";
            QrString += "\"TEL:\" + telephone + \";\" +"; 
            QrString += "\"ADR:\" + pobox + \",\" + room + \",\" + house + \",\" + city + \",\" + prefecture + \",\" + zip + \",\" + country + \",\" + company + \",\" + fax + \";\" +";
            QrString += "\"TITLE:\"  + job + \";\" +";
            QrString += "\"NOTE:\" + note + \";\" +";
            QrString += "\"END:VCARD\" +";
            QrString += "\";\";";
```

Can someone tell me, whether this format is correct and what mistake I am doing here??

Update : 
I used new line character like this :

```
  QrString += "var compiled_card_data = \"BEGIN:VCARD\" \r\n ";
            QrString += "\"VERSION:3.0\" \r\n ";
            QrString += "\"N:\" + lastname + \";\" + firstname \r\n ";
            QrString += "\"FN:\" + firstname \r\n ";
            QrString += "\"URL:\" + url \r\n ";
            QrString += "\"EMAIL:\" + email \r\n ";
            QrString += "\"TEL:\" + telephone \r\n ";
            QrString += "\"ADR:\" + pobox + \",\" + room + \",\" + house + \",\" + city + \",\" + prefecture + \",\" + zip + \",\" + country + \",\" + company + \",\" + fax \r\n ";
            QrString += "\"TITLE:\"  + job \r\n ";
            QrString += "\"NOTE:\" + note \r\n ";
            QrString += "\"END:VCARD\" \r\n ";
            QrString += "\";\";";
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should have a newline character at the end of each line `\n`.

If that doesn't work, please post an image of the QR which is generated.

A typical (minimal) vCard will look like this.

```
QRstring = "BEGIN:VCARD\n";
QRstring += "N:" + lastname +  ";" + firstname +"\n";
QRstring += "EMAIL:" + email + "\n";
QRstring += "END:VCARD";
```

Try to get a vCard working with just one or two fields first.  That will help you find where the mistakes are.

Comment: Hi i added image and updated my post. It still not working. Please have a look into that.

Comment: The only text that QR code contains is "BEGIN:VCARD".  Whatever you're doing, you're not adding any other text to it!

Comment: But it should take all fields. I dont know what mistake I am doing. Is my code is correct according to you??

Comment: No, your code is not correct - why do you have `\"` all over the place?  Look at the sample vCard on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard

Comment: Hi I am really stucked here. can you show me one part of my code how to implement this? I tried to remove slash like this,  QrString += "URL: + url \r\n "; but if i do like this then QR code doesnt detect my code.

Comment: Hi problem I am facing is, line break is not working. I tried to use \n and \r\n, but when i scan, all results are displayed in one line. I got to know that,%0A is the encoded one for line break. So what I should use to insert line breaks after every line??